# Avoiding NAs when using ifelse to create a dummy variable

Tags: r, if-statement, logical-operators

I am encountering some trouble trying to create a dummy variable in a dataset, based on conditions in other variables. My question is probably less about code and more about logic, so the solution might just consist in getting all the logical operators right. But at that I have been failing.

I will copy my actual code here so that I don't inadvertently remove my mistake in creating a generic sample.

"Eb" is a dataset consisting of a Eurobarometer survey, and I am interested in three variables in it. I want to assign values of 1 to a specific response pattern, and 0 to all respondents not exhibiting this pattern. A missing value in one or more of the relevant variables should assign a 0. The following code works:

```
      eb$dummy1 <- ifelse(eb$v246 == 1 & !is.na(eb$v246) & eb$v247 == 1 & !is.na(eb$v247) 
& eb$v250 == 4 & !is.na(eb$v250), "1", "0")
        
            table(is.na(eb$dummy1))
            FALSE 
            12995
```

But if I want to relax the selection criteria so that not only the strong agrees/disagrees count, but also the slight agrees/disagrees, it does not work anymore.

```
    eb$dummy2 <- ifelse (!is.na(eb$v246) & eb$v246 == 1 | eb$v246 == 2 
& !is.na(eb$v247) & eb$v247 == 1 | eb$v247 == 2 
& !is.na(eb$v250) & eb$v250 == 4 | eb$v250 == 3, "1", "0")
        
        table(is.na(eb$dummy2))
        FALSE  TRUE 
        11769  1226
```

What's especially strange is that as I change the order of the arguments following `ifelse`, the number of NAs fluctuates (between 1000 and 1400). That's why I'm suspecting that I am just not using the logical operators correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: As has been requested/suggested in some of your previous questions, please provide sample data. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on the use of `dput`, `data.frame`, or `read.table` to provide unambiguous sample data. Thanks!

Comment: `?Syntax` stows the precedence of different operators, and `&` is higher than `|`, so some brackets are needed around the pairs of non-`NA` values.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the links, will make sure to comply next time!

Comment: @Miff Thanks, that's all it took for it to work now!